# What does it mean to say 'Is bit 7 on?' in a calculator flowchart?

Tags: python, calculator, bit, flowchart, 7-bit

http://home.fnal.gov/~cheung/embedded-linux/pics/flowchart4.gif

^ The flowchart

I am going to writing a code in Python for a calculator, so I found this flowchart, I was just wondering does anyone know what 'Is bit 7 on?' means!

Comment: `on` means `set to 1` rather than `0` in binary.

Comment: the flow chart will probably be less than helpful for writing a calculator in python ... unless its for the raspberry pi and you have a calculator pad wired to the gpio maybe ...

Answer (score 1):

0b1000000  would be the seventh bit

so you can check it by

```
if value & 0b1000000: print "7th bit on"
```

although in this flow chart it is a signal that tells the system to keep accepting inputs ...

really though you need to know things like if it is actually the 8th bit (0 based indexing), or if its stored in little or big endian.